# iron.io / iron_worker scheduling task run_every is ignored....(using ruby gem),

Tags: iron

using iron.io within rails app. their ironcasts have been really good and its pretty simple.
weird behaviour is that i've setup a scheduled task during rails startup (application.rb), i've set scheduled task to 10min (600 seconds), but the tasks are being kicked off every minute (or so, almost as if its ... as often as possible).

The tasks create and run. The first one connects to my heroku DB, but other tasks often fail (connection issue, but *I think* this is because its happening so quickly).

```
schedule = @iwclient.schedules.create("schedule", {:database => dbsettings },{:run_every => 600 } )
```

have I missed something?

- I have tried different timings, does not seem to make a difference.
- i've got debug output displaying the results of the task creation e.g. puts schedule.inspect.to_s

welcome any guidance if anyone has had similar issues

Ben

these are db settings are confirmed during iron_worker task debug output that they are correctly populated, indeed the task does execute and exit ok.

```
dbsettings = {
:adapter => "postgresql",
:database => "xxx",
:host => "ec2-107-20-224-35.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
:port => 5432,
:username =>  "xxxx",
:password => "xxx",
:sslmode => "require"}
```